# two row header in mvc3 WebGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

Is there any way to have a two row header in a WebGrid ?

I looked for a way to do custom rendering for the header or for a way to only render the body of the table (without the table tags), but I couldn't find anything.

I would like to create a webgrid that looks something like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
|grouped cols                |grouped cols|
-------------------------------------------
|col1 |  col2 | col3 | col4  | col5 |col6 |
-------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------
|d1   |  d2   | d3   | d4    | d5   |d6   |
-------------------------------------------
|d1   |  d2   | d3   | d4    | d5   |d6   |
-------------------------------------------
|d1   |  d2   | d3   | d4    | d5   |d6   |
-------------------------------------------
```

Keep in mind that I am new to mvc3 (so I might miss the obvious solution).

Answer (score 4):

Server side solution:

```
@(new HtmlString(grid.GetHtml(Your grid definition).ToHtmlString()
    .Replace("<thead>",""<thead><tr class='webgrid-header'><th scope='col' colspan='4'>cols 1 to 4</th><th scope='col' colspan='2'>cols 5 and 6</th></tr>")))
```

Client side (Assuming only one webgrid in the view you could use some jquery):

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script>
    $(function () {
        var th = $("<tr class='webgrid-header'><th scope='col' colspan='4'>col 1 to 4</th><th scope='col' colspan='2'>col 5 and 6</th></tr>")
        $("thead").prepend(th);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build it with html  element. You should use colspan and rowspan to group cells. Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830506/how-do-you-use-colspan-and-rowspan-in-html-tables);