# How to make a single cell taller and span two rows

Tags: html-table

I have a table and I'd like to make one cell in a row taller than the others and then on the next row it would flow to the right of the first cell from the previous row.

This is what I have so far:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4">aaaaaaaa</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td want this one to be two rows high>a</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> //want this row to fit in the right of top row
    <td>b</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You might be looking for the `rowspan` attribute. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9830506/945456

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you need

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1" >aaaaaaaa</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> <!--want this row to fit in the right of top row-->
    <td></td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I found it later, it was rowspan that i was looking for, but thanks anyway!