# Cells align html CSS table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Help me please get this structure. I have:

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
   <td>left</td>
   <td>rigth</td>
   <td>bottom1</td>
   <td>bottom2</td>
   <td>bottom3</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image]

Comment: That is not tabular data. Why do you think a table should be involved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you use colspan and rowspan in HTML tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830506/how-do-you-use-colspan-and-rowspan-in-html-tables)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use tables for layout - if that is the case, please, please don't! :)

Comment: start here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: @Quentin What is tabular data and how should EagleSH know? Provide some resource for learning about it.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Tabular+data

Comment: LMGTFY responses aren't particularly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>left</td>
        <td>rigth</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">bottom1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">bottom2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">bottom3</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Comment: +1 for keeping the typo of "rigth", and for best answer.

Comment: This does not work in JSFiddle.

Comment: With the context of the question there are implied opening and closing `table` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for multiple rows, defined by `tr`. To replicate your image, you would need 'left' and 'right' in one `tr`, then each other cell in its own `tr`. To get the lower cells to span over the width of two cells, use `colspan`.

```
<tr>
  <td>left</td>
  <td>right</td>
</tr><tr>
  <td colspan="2">bottom1</td>
</tr>...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/V7LNm/

```
    <table>
  <tr>
    <td>left</td>
    <td>right</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">bottom 1</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">bottom 2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">bottom 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also add additional options to what smdrager posted

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">left</td>
        <td align="center">right</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2">Bottom 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2">Bottom 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td align="center" colspan="2">Bottom 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VHWT9/