# GridView vs. ListView vs.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, gridview, telerik

I have the following sample data in a list:

```
Company-----City-----State-----Salesperson
FakeCo------Test-----FL--------Jim
FakeCo------Test-----FL--------John
FakeCo------Test-----FL--------Sue
Acme--------Foo------CA--------Jane
Oscorp------Bar------NY--------Steve
Oscorp------Bar------NY--------Bob
```

EDIT: The data in this list is not static and changes regularly depending on query parameters.

As you can see, there are three companies with redundant data and multiple salespeople for each company.  What I would like to do, is take this data and display it in a fashion with a little less repetition on an aspx page.  Here is a quick example of what I would like to accomplish:

[image]

I have tried using both Telerik's RadGridView and their RadListView, but I can't seem to get it right.  I am not sure if I will need to nest the controls or not.  I also am unsure whether either of these controls is even the best way to accomplish my goal, they are simply the first things that came to mind.

I understand that this is a vague question (and subjective), but I am looking for opinions on what is the best way to display grouped, tabular data.  Examples, links, etc. would be especially helpful, too!

Comment: is there any reason why you need a databound control ? can't you simply do an html table ?

Comment: @user3077371 - no, it does not need to be a databound control as this is simply for display purposes.  I was only using the RadGrid and RadListView because they are what I am most comfortable with.  I am open to any suggestions and examples.

Comment: I like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830506/how-do-you-use-colspan-and-rowspan-in-html-tables

Comment: It looks like that works with static data, but I do not see how to use that with non-static data.  My apologies for not mentioning earlier that the data in my list changes (format stays the same).  I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these steps. The code is self-explanatory

Create two classes

```
// this is the original class you have
public class CompanyDetails
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string SalesPerson { get; set; }
}
//this is to help you with the display
public class GroupedCompanyDetails
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public List<string> SalesPerson { get; set; }
}
```

Now DataBind the ListView after the below conversion like this

```
List<CompanyDetails> details = GetCompanyDetails();
IEnumerable<GroupedCompanyDetails> groupedDetails = details
    .GroupBy(sp => new { sp.Company, sp.City, sp.State })
    .Select(gsp => new GroupedCompanyDetails()
    {
        Address = String.Format("{0}<br/>{1}, {2}", gsp.Key.Company, gsp.Key.City, gsp.Key.State),
        SalesPerson = gsp.Select(x => x.SalesPerson).ToList()
    });

MasterLS.DataSource = groupedDetails;
MasterLS.DataBind();
```

Supporting markup will be

```
<asp:ListView ID="MasterLS" runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
        <table class="salesmantable">
            <tbody>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" /> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# Eval("Address") %></td>
            <td>
                <asp:ListView ID="SalesmanLS" runat="server" 
                            DataSource='<%# Eval("SalesPerson") %>'>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Container.DataItem %><hr />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Additionally, if you want table inside the second td try this markup,

```
<asp:ListView ID="SalesmanLS" runat="server" 
            DataSource='<%# Eval("SalesPerson") %>'>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table class="salesmanchildtable">
            <tbody>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" /> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr><td><%# Container.DataItem %></td></tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Disclaimer: My ListView is a little rusty. Dunno if there are any better methods. Too much MVC nowadays ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you have on the data you provide is called un-normalized data (going back to data bases theory), so you basically have a master-detail relationship that would be in 2 different tables if it was normalized, like:

```
ID   Company-----City-----State
1----FakeCo------Test-----FL
2----Acme--------Foo------CA
3----Oscorp------Bar------NY

Salesperson----Company ID
Jim------------1
John-----------1
Sue------------1
Jane-----------2
Steve----------3
Bob------------3
```

With this in mind, there's several ways to display data as you want it, using a single data source  like you have it or splitting it into 2 different data sources related on a master-detail relationship. So what you need to look for is master-detail layouts on asp .net.

Don't necessarily think about it as using a single control approach to achieve this, even though most of third party's data binding controls provide this kind of data layout, for instance the one you mentioned, Telerik's RadGridView, here's some samples they have for this kind of layout:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/grouping/grouping/defaultcs.aspx

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-binding/master-detail/defaultcs.aspx

However, you can also achieve this with built-in ASP .NET controls, and remember you can always use nested data controls like: http://elpolloprogrammer.com/index.php/master-detail-gridview-in-asp-net-c/