# How to split two cells into different numbers of rows?

Tags: ms-word

I have a 1 * 2 table. I need to split the left column into two rows evenly, and the right column into three rows with the same height. Is it possible in word? Or is it possible in html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using Microsoft Word

You can't do this with Microsoft Word's "Split" tool.

However, try this work around (**the order of steps is important**):

> 1. In your Word document, create a table with 6 rows and 2 columns
>
> [image: Table in Word with 6 rows and 2 columns]
>
> 2. On the left column, select trios of cells (threes) and merge them (Right Click > Merge Cells)
>
> [image: Merging trios of cells in the left hand column]
>
> 3. On the right, select pairs of cells (twos) and merge them.
>
> [image: Final result - 2 cells on the left, 3 cells on the right]

*Note: This works for me using Microsoft Word 2013*

#### Using HTML

Take a look at - [How do you use colspan and rowspan in HTML tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830506/how-do-you-use-colspan-and-rowspan-in-html-tables)