# How to show values vertically in bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am generating a reports for NGO which do surveys of school I have generated reports than they have sent there format. It can be done easily via simple table structure but I want to do it through Bootstrap classes for table. Especially the vertical alignment of the text in reports.

I have search around for vertical columns and design etc. but I didn't found some, please help me out. What I need is to show `proj#` `proj code` `proj name` `proj goal` column in center and in vertical like the image given below .

here what I need to develop.[image]

And here what I have made for them :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think table layout will be very much suited for this purpose. While if you're moving from table layout then i would recommend `for loop or while` in your code. Prepare an array or mysql table and call values through database. You will be better off maintaining table in databases rather than bootstrap or table classes. Still i feel you should keep table layout, it is flexible. [Try this site for tutorial](http://zetcode.com/databases/mysqlphptutorial/)

For transformation of word, you can use `transform: rotate(90 deg);` in css

```
.vertical-text {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: left center 0;
padding-top:50px;
}

<td rowspan="2">
```

Replace the value of rowspan with row count from database.The table will look just as in paper with column correctly merged.

[More about rowspan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830506/how-do-you-use-colspan-and-rowspan-in-html-tables)

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ddcucxp/)

Comment: well i am dynamically rendring the table data coming from database and i am using foreach loop to display all data all is set except the format of report they want me to generate this kind of report i am talking about the first image

Comment: `rowspan=array.length - 1` this is the way to go. In your CAI td put row span and provide array length as output.http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/th/rowspan

Comment: Although rowspan worked fine but it create another problem which is it disturb other column in bootstrap table

Comment: that's why i fly away from using frameworks for css. I use my own created little foundation css. Minimum headache for !important and less padding margin confusions due to border-box and clearfix.

Comment: yeah great buddy i just fiqured out i have to count my array and put that array in `rowspan=<? $myarrsize; ?>` and it will fit automatically in table you help me alot and learned a good thing today