# HTML5, Jquery Excel like Column Grouping

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, excel

I am new to HTML, JQUery.

Requirement is to create HTML5 Table in Asp.net MVC as below. Columns in group.

How can I read from Table rows and cells after click on Save

[image]

Comment: You mean [`rowspan`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830506/how-do-you-use-colspan-and-rowspan-in-html-tables)?

Comment: How can I read from Table after click on Save

Answer (score 2):

Use HTML's `colspan` attribute.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">April</th>
        <th colspan="3">May</th>
        <th colspan="3">June</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item Count</td>
        <td>Item Cost</td>
        <td>Total Cost</td>

        <td>Item Count</td>
        <td>Item Cost</td>
        <td>Total Cost</td>

        <td>Item Count</td>
        <td>Item Cost</td>
        <td>Total Cost</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the below solution, but let me know if anything better than this.

```
   $("#saveBtn").click(function() {
            var rows = $('#table > tbody > tr');
            var data = [];
            $.each(rows, function(index, val) {
                var values = [];
                $(this).find('td input').each(function (i, v) {
                    values.push({
                        Key: $(this).attr('name'),
                        Val: $(this).val()

                    });

                });
                data.push({
                    Values: values,
                    Id:val.id
                });

            });

        });
```