# I want to create a nested table or table row

Tags: html, html-table

When I use nested `<table>` or nested `<tr>` , I can't create a column like that . Can anyone help me ????.
This picture is exactly what I want .

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the HTML [`colspan`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/th/colspan) and [`rowspan`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/th/rowspan) attributes.

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>        
     </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}

td {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/04yjcL2e/1/

For more information about `colspan` and `rowspan` see this post:

- [How do you use colspan and rowspan in HTML tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830506/how-do-you-use-colspan-and-rowspan-in-html-tables)

Comment: that's not exactly I want but maybe I can use it . Anw , thank you so much

Comment: actually, i'm working on the complete table right now.. will need a few more minutes... you're right, trickier than i thought

Comment: Yup , It's very complex . I have been thinking about it for hours . But I can't do it

Comment: perfect . Thank you so much