# Create table with colspan in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-7, html-table

May I know how to create a table which can add colspan in the table ? Which module can do it ? I been search for hours but only [Table Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/tablefield) plugin so far I found. It cannot add colspan within.

Is there anyway to do it ?

Comment: How about using WYSIWYG editor, like imce?

Comment: imce is use to upload image. i dont think it can create a table

Comment: Ah, true, sorry. I thought of some wysiwyg editor, like CKE.

Comment: I think [*this answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9830847/4058484) might help..