# How to create a HTML table that goes from single to double back to single

Tags: html, html-table

I'm having a little trouble making a HTML table that follows this structure

[image: Table example]

Can anyone shine any light on how this would be created?

Comment: What sort of data do you have that would be appropriate to express in a table of that shape?

Comment: You are looking for [`rowspan`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830506/how-do-you-use-colspan-and-rowspan-in-html-tables) - but as Quentin insinuates above, there may be better ways to do this with modern CSS. `<table>` elements should generally be used for the representation of tabular data.

Answer (score -2):

You could also use colspan as well as rowspan. Same formatting:

```
<td colspan="2"></td>
```

Comment: No, colspan won't help with this.

Comment: @Quentin Wanna delete that?

Comment: Delete what, his comment? Why?

Comment: just thought it would be informative to let OP know that there's an option to merge columns as well as rows. Might be helpful for him in the future!