# Underscore.js to filter out the unique values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, underscore.js

Here is a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/6xytngz7/) to my Fiddle

I have a table that is created dynamically from the JSON obtained from a Ajax response.

I have duplicate entries in the table. For example `xxx,xxx`. 
I want to group them and have it like `<td data-count="some count">xxx</td>`

I tried using `underscore.js` but it seems to break the `rowspan` functionality.

I converted the `arr` into a object using `_countBy(arr)` and I obtained an object of the following format.

`{xxx: 2, zzz: 1}`

**Question** : How can I modify the `generateTable()` function to accommodate this change. I tried to modify it the following way

```
var i=0;

$.each(queryObject,function(key,value){
   if(i == 0){
       i++;
       childrenHtml += ('<td rowspan="1" data-count="'+value+'">' + key + '</td>' + '</tr>');
   }
   else{
    childrenHtml += ('<tr><td rowspan="1" data-count="'+value+'">' + key + '</td>' + '</tr>');
   }
});
```

But the rowspan seems to be problem now. How can I modify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make function like this to convert your data and group it:

```
  _.chain(data.result)
    .keys()//get all the keys buildname1 buildname2..etc
    .flatten()
    .each(function(key) {//for each key do a mapping and return a grouping.
      data.result[key] = _.chain(data.result[key]).flatten().map(function(d) {
        var key = _.chain(d).keys().first().value();
        var ob = {};
        ob[key] = _.chain(d).values().flatten().groupBy().value();//grouping by value
        return ob;
      }).value();
    }).value();
```

This will convert your data set into this format:

```
{
   "buildname1":[
      {
         "table1":{
            "xxx":[
               "xxx"
            ],
            "zzz":[
               "zzz",
               "zzz"
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "table2":{
            "xxx":[
               "xxx"
            ],
            "yyy":[
               "yyy"
            ]
         }
      }
   ],
   "buildname2":[
      {
         "table1":{
            "xxx":[
               "xxx",
               "xxx"
            ],
            "zzz":[
               "zzz"
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "table2":{
            "xxx":[
               "xxx",
               "xxx"
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "table3":{
            "xxx":[
               "xxx"
            ],
            "yyy":[
               "yyy"
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Then you will need to change the biz logic for making table, and calculating rowspan.

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/3n8xv3hL/)

Comment: If we have an empty array in any of child i.e in this case say `"table1": []` table structure breaks. Any idea on how to fix this?