# React.js- Dynamic table with rowspan

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I am trying to create a dynamic table, using this example- [Dynamic & Complex rowspan in HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330484/dynamic-complex-rowspan-in-html-table)

I am trying to replicate the similar thing in react.js

I have put a closing tr tag  in conditional rendering if the index is 0.
However, it gives me ' Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <>'

The state 'data' object which I got from back-end is something like -

```
{
  "100": [
    "ABC"
  ],
  "101": [
    "123",
    "DEF",
    "XYZ",
    "456",
    "657",
    "1234",
    "4564",
    "vdfgx",
    "vcegefgg",
    "g544"
  ]
}
```

I have written following code in component to create dynamic table.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Reason</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {Object.keys(this.state.data).map(
            (error_code, i) => {
                return (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <tr> 
                            <td
                                rowSpan={
                                    this.state.data[
                                        error_code
                                    ].length
                                }
                                key={i}
                            >
                                {error_code}
                            </td>
                            {this.state.data[
                                error_code
                            ].map((error_description, index) => (
                                <React.Fragment>
                                    {index === 0 ? (
                                        <React.Fragment>
                                            <td
                                                key={index}
                                                rowSpan="1"
                                            >
                                                {error_description}
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>                //<---  HERE
                                        </React.Fragment>
                                    ) : (
                                        <tr>
                                            <td
                                                key={index}
                                                rowSpan="1"
                                            >
                                                {error_description}
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    )}
                                </React.Fragment>
                            ))}
                    </React.Fragment>
                );
            }
        )}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the final output something like -

```
   <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="1">100</td>
        <td rowspan="1">ABC</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="10">101</td>
        <td rowspan="1">123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="1">DEF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="1">XYZ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="1">456</td>
    </tr>
    .....

   </tbody>
```

Could anyone please guide me the correct way to achieve the desired output ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSX, like XML, requires proper nesting `<><tr>...</tr></>` and does not support overlapping tags like `<><tr></></tr>`. You need to structure your code in a way to preserve proper nesting:

```
  <tbody>
    {Object.keys(this.state.data).map((error_code, i) => {
      return this.state.data[error_code].map((error_description, index) =>
        index === 0 ? (
          <tr>
            <td rowSpan={this.state.data[error_code].length} key={i}>
              {error_code}
            </td>
            <td key={index} rowSpan="1">
              {error_description}
            </td>
          </tr>
        ) : (
          <tr>
            <td key={index} rowSpan="1">
              {error_description}
            </td>
          </tr>
        )
      )
    })}
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

JSX does not generate a string. It generates a tree-like structure built out of function calls and Objects.  Any `<tag></tag>` translates into a function call, that's why your code is invalid.
You need to rethink this component.
Split the data processing and decision making into a separate function that does only that and returns the *final* data to be rendered. Then loop/map through it in `render` and return the elements structure.