# Some rows in a row html

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want table such like that as show in image, I tried to merge cells but not succeed. here is my code without merging:

[image: I want table such like that as show in image, I tried to merge cells but not succeed. here is my code without merging.]

```css
.tftable {margin: 10px auto;font-size:12px;color:#333333;width:auto;border-width: 1px;border-color: #5e823a;border-collapse: collapse;}
.tftable th {font-weight: 800;font-size:24px;background-color:#46622a;border-width: 2px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #5e823a;text-align:left;color: #fcfcfc;}
.tftable tr {background-color:#88b35d;}
.tftable td {font-weight: 600;font-size:18px;border-width: 2px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #5e823a;}
```

```html
<table class="tftable" border="1">
 <tr>
  <th>SuperVisors</th>
 </tr>
</table>
<table class="tftable" border="1">
 <tr>
  <th>Armina</th>
  <th>Saleen</th>
  <th>Julia</th>
  <th>Samina</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><img src="http://www.dhresource.com/albu_962922772_00/1.200x200.jpg" alt="Super Visors" height="200" width="200"></td>
  <td><img src="http://www.dhresource.com/albu_962922772_00/1.200x200.jpg" alt="Super Visors" height="200" width="200"></td>
  <td><img src="http://www.dhresource.com/albu_962922772_00/1.200x200.jpg" alt="Super Visors" height="200" width="200"></td>
  <td><img src="http://www.dhresource.com/albu_962922772_00/1.200x200.jpg" alt="Super Visors" height="200" width="200"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: related one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830506/how-do-you-use-colspan-and-rowspan-in-html-tables

Answer (score 0):

Easy. `colspan` attribute:

```css
.tftable {margin: 10px auto;font-size:12px;color:#333333;width:auto;border-width: 1px;border-color: #5e823a;border-collapse: collapse;}
.tftable th {font-weight: 800;font-size:24px;background-color:#46622a;border-width: 2px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #5e823a;text-align:left;color: #fcfcfc;}
.tftable tr {background-color:#88b35d;}
.tftable td {font-weight: 600;font-size:18px;border-width: 2px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #5e823a;}
```

```html
<table class="tftable" border="1">
    <thead>
 <tr>
  <th colspan="4">SuperVisors</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>Armina</th>
  <th>Saleen</th>
  <th>Julia</th>
  <th>Samina</th>
 </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td><img src="http://www.dhresource.com/albu_962922772_00/1.200x200.jpg" alt="Super Visors" height="200" width="200"></td>
  <td><img src="http://www.dhresource.com/albu_962922772_00/1.200x200.jpg" alt="Super Visors" height="200" width="200"></td>
  <td><img src="http://www.dhresource.com/albu_962922772_00/1.200x200.jpg" alt="Super Visors" height="200" width="200"></td>
  <td><img src="http://www.dhresource.com/albu_962922772_00/1.200x200.jpg" alt="Super Visors" height="200" width="200"></td>
 </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note `<tbody>` and `<thead>` tags.