# HTML-CSS table troubleshoot3

Tags: html, css

I just start learning html and css, can someone tell me how to make this table using html and css, I am stuck. I would really appreciate that. Here is the [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvzkD.jpg)

Comment: you have to use colspan and rowspan to accomplish this..http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_td_colspan.asp

Comment: add your code so everyone can see where you stuck and you will get your answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rowspan` and `colspan` to create cells that spans over multiple rows or columns. You would need some cells that span over 4 columns and some that span over 5 rows. Here are some tutorials (you'll need to scroll down to `colspan` and `rowspan` or "Merging Cells"):

- [How do you use colspan and rowspan in HTML tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830506/how-do-you-use-colspan-and-rowspan-in-html-tables)
- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp
- http://abacles.com/html-tables.html