# How to create rowspan like below in HTML

Tags: html

Can someone help me to create a table similar to than i tried all examples here they are not helping. In Html[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use colspan and rowspan in HTML tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830506/how-do-you-use-colspan-and-rowspan-in-html-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">My Saving</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">My Saving</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that is what i wanted.

Comment: You`re welcome...

Answer (score 0):

Use `rowspan="2"`

Check out w3 schools for reference

http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_rowspan