# How to create a table using colspan, rowspan or css in html?

Tags: html, css

[image]

How can I create a table like the above example using HTML and CSS. I've tried the following:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>XXX</th>
    <th>XXX</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>XXX</td>
    <td>XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>XXX</td>
    <td>XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>XXX</td>
    <td>XXX</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but it won't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: You'll need to use a combination of `colspan` and `rowspan`.

Comment: get some knowledge about using `rowspan` and `colspan`. It is not that difficult to understand. [here is the help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9830847/5015089)

Comment: thanks @HiddenHobbes and Mian Haseeb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:50%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @abnishekPandey

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr>
<th colspan="2">XXX</th>
<th colspan="2">XXX</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">XXX</td>
<td colspan="2">XXX</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">XXX</td>
<td rowspan="2">XXX</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">XXX</td>
<td>XXX</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">XXX</td>
<td rowspan="2">XXX</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>XXX</td>
<td>XXX</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">XXX</td>
<td rowspan="2">XXX</td>
</tr>
```