# Creating HTML Table using CSS efffects

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm developing a webpage where I want to insert a table as seen in the image. I know how to use HTML tables, but I'm confused of creating this. I tried a lot to do this, but they are not working as I want. Please If some one could give me a guidance to develop this table I really appreciate it.

[image]

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" style="border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center; float: right;" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="2">Table Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Type </th>
      <th>Orders<br />Phone/Fax/Email/Post</th>
      <th>Number</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Type 1</td>
      <td>Order 1</td>
      <td>Num 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Type 2</td>
      <td>Order 2</td>
      <td>Num 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Type 3</td>
      <td>Order 3</td>
      <td>Num 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Type 4</td>
      <td>Order 4</td>
      <td>Num 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Type 5</td>
      <td>Order 5</td>
      <td>Num 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This does not give my desired output

Comment: And where is this table you say you created? Maybe show us your work and we'll try to help you out from there.

Comment: give your sample code so that we can assist you

Answer (score 0):

1. `File`
2. `Save as`
3. choose filename
4. change file type to `HTML Page`
5. inspect HTML

If you want to handcraft this table have a look at `colspan` and `rowspan` or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830506/how-do-you-use-colspan-and-rowspan-in-html-tables)