# How can I merge row and column in HTML as the picture below?

Tags: html

How can I merge row and column as the figure blow in HTML?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830506/how-do-you-use-colspan-and-rowspan-in-html-tables

Answer (score 1):

After trying many times, I found the solution.

```
    <table border="1">  
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">No</td>
        <td rowspan="3">Province</td>
        <td colspan="2">Level</td>
        <td>Other</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">XL</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>001</td>
        <td>Province #1</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>002</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```