# HTML table with 2 row and 6 column

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create normal html table, row with two column and column with six row.

[image: image showing the table]

I want to create html table according to above pic.

Comment: by generate, what do you mean?
it is a normal HTML table that you wish to create using <tr> and <td> ?
If so, hint: use colspan and rowspan!!

Comment: have a look at colspan and rowspan attributes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use colspan and rowspan in HTML tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830506/how-do-you-use-colspan-and-rowspan-in-html-tables)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px; font-size: 0.8em;" border="1px">
    <tr align="center" >
        <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 10%;" rowspan="2">S No</th>
        <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 55%;" rowspan="2">Subject</th>
        <th style="padding:2.5px;" colspan="2">Term-1</th>
        <th style="padding:2.5px;" colspan="2">Term-2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>PA1</th>
        <th>Notebook</th>
        <th>PA2</th>
        <th>Notebook2</th>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir.