# Table row background color not filling the whole row

Tags: html, css

I have a simple table that has a row at the top with one `td` element and the ones under it have 3 `td`s here is the structure :

```html
<tr class="type">
  <td>
    <span>Platform</span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="type__el">
  <td>OS</td>
  <td class="value">WINDOWS</td>
  <td class="score"> 8.6</td>
</tr>
```

So im trying to set the background color for the first row but it doesn't work properly it only highlights the text :

[image]

```css
.type {
 background-color : #ccc;
}
```

i've tried adding 3 `td`s to the row and it works but not clean since i see these gaps between them :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expend `<td>` in first row by using property `colspan="3"`

Result

```css
.type {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="type" bgcolor="red">
    <td colspan="3">
      <span>Platform</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="type__el">
    <td>OS</td>
    <td class="value">WINDOWS</td>
    <td class="score"> 8.6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `colspan` attribute, a value of `3` should work

```css
.type {
 background-color : #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="type" bgcolor="red">
      <td colspan="3">
        <span>Platform</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="type__el">
      <td>OS</td>
      <td class="value">WINDOWS</td>
      <td class="score"> 8.6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can read more about it on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830506/how-do-you-use-colspan-and-rowspan-in-html-tables)