# Is this table possible in HTML

Tags: html, reactjs

I am wondering if this table layout in HTML possible? here is what I have in Reactjs:

[image]

I am getting errors trying to do a colspan.

What I want to achieve is this layout:

[image]

Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps

Comment: `<td colspan="3">Remark: Blah blah blah</td>`

Comment: Yes it is. Make it 3 columns and use `colspan`.

Comment: @Nat What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use colspan and rowspan in HTML tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830506/how-do-you-use-colspan-and-rowspan-in-html-tables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes it is possible with `colspan`, here is the example code

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>title</th>
    <th>edit</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jhon doe</td>
    <td>Sales</td>
    <td>Edit</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Remark : blablabla</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Jane doe</td>
    <td>Sales</td>
    <td>Edit</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Remark : blablabla</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but you will need css to add borders

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's how you wanted your table to be, use `colspan` after which cell you need divided columns.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: left;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.
You can read this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp).

But to save your time you just need to set `colspan=3` in your `td` where you want it to be expanded.